# CPTUI rewrite disable when no post in CPTUI has been found

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting

I have a CPTUI with the following data:

```
function cptui_register_my_cpts_activaties() {

    /**
     * Post Type: Activaties.
     */

    $labels = array(
        "name" => __( "Activaties", "red-button" ),
        "singular_name" => __( "Activatie", "red-button" ),
    );

    $args = array(
        "label" => __( "Activaties", "red-button" ),
        "labels" => $labels,
        "description" => "",
        "public" => false,
        "publicly_queryable" => true,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "delete_with_user" => false,
        "show_in_rest" => true,
        "rest_base" => "",
        "rest_controller_class" => "WP_REST_Posts_Controller",
        "has_archive" => false,
        "show_in_menu" => true,
        "show_in_nav_menus" => true,
        "exclude_from_search" => false,
        "capability_type" => "post",
        "map_meta_cap" => true,
        "hierarchical" => true,
        "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "activaties", "with_front" => false ),
        "query_var" => true,
        "supports" => array( "title" ),
    );

    register_post_type( "activaties", $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_cpts_activaties' );
```

Now I have created a page as well, which is a subpage of another page.
That looks likes this:

```
- Activaties
-- Aanleveren
```

So the url for `Aanleveren` becomes `/activaties/aanleveren`, which is the exact same of the CPTUI.

**What I want:**
When the post is NOT found as a CPTUI, I want to query the `post_type` *page*.

Is this possible? If so, how can I achieve this?

Comment: CPT UI is a plugin, do you just mean CPT (Custom Post Type)?

Comment: Sorry, yes I meant CPT indeed

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you are searching for post and if post not found then you want to display page.

If you are using **WordPress default search** then you can try this code

```
function my_cptui_add_post_type_to_search( $query ) {

if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() ) {
    return;
}

if ( $query->is_search() ) {
    $query->set(
        'post_type',
        array( 'post', 'page' )
    );
  }

}

add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_cptui_add_post_type_to_search' );
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not searching for a post. the CPTUI has the same slug and therefore it looks for a post with post_type 'activaties'. There the post is not found, therefore I want to lookup posts with post_type 'page'